# xcode cloud adding workflow errors "this operation could not be complete"

Tags: xcode, react-native, xcode-cloud

Developing an iOS app on react native, trying to use xcode cloud for the first time.

When adding a workflow I'm getting this error:

[image]

As you can see the error message isn't useful, and I couldn't find anything on line (probably because it's a new beta feature by xcode)

Any ideas on how to even approach this?

In case it matters, I tried various variations of this file as the documentation:

```
# ios/ci_scripts/ci_post_clone.sh (it's executable)

#!/bin/sh

## V1
brew install cocoapods
brew install node
brew install yarn
yarn
pod install

## V2
export HOMEBREW_NO_INSTALL_CLEANUP=TRUE
brew install cocoapods
# have to add node yourself
brew install node@16
# link it to the path
brew link node@16

brew install yarn

# Install dependencies you manage with CocoaPods.
yarn
pod install
# the sed command from RN cant find the file... so we have to run it ourselves
sed -i -e $'s/ && (__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED < __IPHONE_10_0)//' /Volumes/workspace/repository/ios/Pods/RCT-Folly/folly/portability/Time.h
```

Answer (score 1):

I restarted xcode, waited for 2 hours, and tried again, and it worked.

Comment: I have configured the V2 on your `ci_post_clone.sh` but I am getting errors where it starts to build but fails when running this file. Have you had any issues lately?

Comment: i don't know why apple do this kind of stuff...

Comment: just quitting and restarting Xcode again works for me ...